# JobLib | PicklingError: Could not pickle the task to send it to the workers

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing, jupyter-notebook, pickle, joblib

I am wanting to run many invocations of Neural Network *GPT-2* by *HappyFace*.

It works without stand-alone:

```
%%time
for invoc in invoc_list:
    val_list = query(invoc, entries)
    val_list
>>> Wall time: 32.8 s
>>> ['"I think we all knew the first part of The First World War."\n\nThe question of how the people got to where they are in the United States isn\'t entirely clear, but it involves a series of complex and',
'from a lowly high school English teacher to the highest political executive in Israel when the Nazis captured that state in 1941, she wrote in her 1945 biography the "secret" book on the Nazi regime:\n\n"Among the Nazi',
'It is said that the woman of the North Sea was one of the most powerful of the Seven Sisters; and many of them were able to overcome other men. She is described as a "Great Great Woman from the',
'In a series of letters of his heredity to a classmate in a college near his home, she was asked by him to take her down to her home in Florida where she lives with her boyfriend, while she tried to']
```

**My aim is to have the above output yielded, but running in parallel via. JobLib.**

However, when *"converting"* my code to `JobLib` code for `parallelisation`; I get the following error:

```
%%time
my_list = Parallel(n_jobs=8)(delayed(query)(invoc, entries) for invoc in invoc_list)
my_list
>>> PicklingError: Could not pickle the task to send it to the workers.
```

---

Notebook:

```
import time
 
# GPT-2
from transformers import pipeline, set_seed
generator = pipeline('text-generation', model='gpt2')
set_seed(42)
 
#import dill as pickle
 
 
def query(payload, entries):
    list_dict = generator(payload, min_length=25, max_length=50, num_return_sequences=entries)
    output = [d['generated_text'].split(payload)[1].strip() for d in list_dict]
    return output
 
invoc_list = ['his her criminal charges include but are not limited to:', 'the defendant was sentenced to:', 'his her education history:']
entries = 4
 
%%time
%%time
for invoc in invoc_list:
    val_list = query(invoc, entries)
    val_list
 
%%time
my_list = Parallel(n_jobs=8)(delayed(query)(invoc, entries) for invoc in invoc_list)
my_list
```

Note: you may need to install:

```
pip3 install joblib
```

```
pip3 install dill
```

Comment: Did you found any solution to this ?